# How do I read from a file and output specific strings in c

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that will read from /etc/passwd and output the username and shell.

For example, here is the first line of the /etc/passwd file:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

I need to only output the user and the shell. In this instance it would print:

```
root:/bin/bash
```

The values are separated by `':'` so I just need to print the string before the first `':'` and the string after the 6th `':'`

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFERSIZE 4096

int printf(const char *text, ...);

int main(void) {
    int fd;
    int buff_size = 1;
    char buff[BUFFERSIZE];
    int size;

    fd = open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("Error opening file \n");
        return -1;
    }

    size = strlen(buff - 17);
    size = size + 1;

    while ((size = read(fd, buff, 1)) > 0) {
        buff[1] = '\0';
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff, size);
    }
}
```

(I am creating prototypes for `printf` because one of the requirements was to write the program without including `<stdio.h>` or `<stdlib.h>`)

Comment: Why are you using file-descriptors and `open()` instead of a file-stream `FILE*` and `fopen()` which makes reading line-oriented input much **much** easier. Reading with `fgets()` instead of `read()` and then using `strtok()` (or just `strchr()` and a counter) would make the task quite easy.

Comment: Off the bat, `size = strlen(buff-17);` passes an address that is not yours to play with to a library function expecting an address of a null terminated string... Off to a bad start... The constraint "don't use these header files" probably means "don't use the functions found in these libraries"... Dangerous to provide your own "hand made" function prototypes for standard library functions...

Comment: (not to mention `buff` in uninitialized which would invoke *Undefined Behavior* in your call with `strlen()` (for a 2nd reason...))

Comment: If/when you figure out how to read "lines" of input from /etc/passwd, research `strchr()` and `strrchr()` to find the first and the last 'colon' in the buffer you've loaded. Those are the two that are interesting to this assignment...

Comment: You can check your output against `awk -F: '{print $1":"$7}' /etc/passwd`

Comment: Writing without `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` means you are stuck with `read()`. But rather than attempting to `read()` an entire `BUFFERSIZE` worth of characters at once, read 1-character at a time, storing the needed characters in `buff` and stopping the read of the line when `'\n'` is encountered.  Keep a counter of each time `':'` is encountered so you know when to stop/start saving the characters in `buff` within each line. In fact, there is no reason to store any of the characters, just read and `write()` if it is one of the needed characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior when you evaluate `strlen(buff - 17)`. It is unclear why you do this.

You can solve the problem with these simple steps:

- read one byte at a time
- count the `':'` on the line
- output the byte if the count is equal to `0` or equal to `6`.
- reset the count at newline (and print the newline)

Note that `read(fd, &b, 1)` and `write(1, &b, 1)` return `-1` in case of error or interruption and should be restarted if `errno` is `EINTR`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    int fd;
    unsigned char b;
    int count;
    ssize_t ret;

    fd = open("/etc/passwd", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) {
        write(2, "Error opening /etc/password\n", 28);
        return 1;
    }

    count = 0;
    for (;;) {
        ret = read(fd, &b, 1);
        if (ret == 0) { // end of file
            break;
        }
        if (ret < 0) { // error
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            write(2, "Read error on /etc/password\n", 28);
            return 1;
        }
        if (b == '\n') {
            // reset count, print b
            count = 0;
        } else
        if (b == ':') {
            // increment count, print ':' only if count == 1
            count = count + 1;
            if (count != 1)
                continue;
        } else
        if (count != 0 && count != 6) {
            // print b only if count is 0 or 6
            continue;
        }
        for (;;) {
            ret = write(1, &b, 1);
            if (ret == 1)
                break;
            if (ret < 0 && errno = EINTR)
                continue;
            write(2, "Write error\n", 12);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use a single loop and a state variable to track the state of where you are in each line based on the number of colons read. The state-variable `ncolon` does that below. Essentially you read every character and check whether the loop is in a state where you should write the character as output or not. You condition the write on the number of colons, whether you are before the 1st or after the last.

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  
  int fd,                   /* file descriptor */
      ofd = STDOUT_FILENO,  /* output file descriptor */
      ncolon = 0;           /* counter - number of colons seen */
  
  /* open file given on command line or read from stdin otherwise */
  if ((fd = argc > 1 ? open (argv[1], O_RDONLY) : STDIN_FILENO) == -1) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  for (;;) {                              /* loop continually */
    unsigned char c;                      /* storage for character */
    int rtn;                              /* var to save return */
  
    if ((rtn = read (fd, &c, 1)) < 1) {   /* validate read of 1 char */
      if (rtn == -1) {                    /* return on error */
        return 1;
      }
      break;                              /* break read loop on EOF */
    }
    
    if (ncolon < 1 || ncolon == 6) {      /* if before 1st or after last */
      write (ofd, &c, 1);                 /* output char */
    }
    
    if (c == '\n') {                      /* reset ncolon on newline */
      ncolon = 0;
    }
    else if (c == ':') {                  /* increment on colon */
      ncolon += 1;
    }
  }
  
  if (fd != STDIN_FILENO) {   /* close file */
    close (fd);
  }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./read_etc-passwd /etc/passwd
root:/bin/bash
messagebus:/usr/bin/false
systemd-network:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:/bin/bash
mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
chrony:/usr/sbin/nologin
...
```

**Confirm the Format**

```
$ diff <(./read_etc-passwd /etc/passwd) <(awk -F: '{print $1":"$7}' /etc/passwd)
```

(no output means program output and `awk` output were identical)